# Best strategy for doing real time, scalable audio processing?

Tags: php, audio, file-upload, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am building a web application that allows users to upload audio files, music in particular. Most of the time, I expect the duration of each song to normally be about several minutes and the file to be approximately 3-10MB in size. However, I would like to accept audio uploads up to about 100MB, possibly allowing for over an hour of audio. I am currently using a combination of FFmpeg, SoX, and LAME to convert from 7 possible formats to mp3 and perform audio modifications including equalization, trimming, and fading. The files are then stored and linked in the database.

My current strategy is to handle the entire process in one HTTP file upload request using PHP on the backend, in which I perform the following functions:

1. Validation
2. Transcode audio into multiple versions (using shell through PHP)
3. Store the original and transcoded versions in a temp directory
4. Upload all audio files to Amazon S3 for permanent storage
5. Commit the ID of each file to a database, linking them to the user

This works very similar to an image processing system I have already set up. However, while images can complete this whole process in just a few seconds, audio can take a lot longer. At most, audio could take about 5-10 minutes to be processed and stored.

**My questions are:**

1. For audio processing, would it be better to fork off the transcoding to another background process, writing its state to the database, and pinging it every few seconds to update the webpage vs. doing it all in one HTTP request?
2. With the intention of scaling in the future, would it be advisable to do all processing on a single server instance, leaving the frontend web instances free to replicate / be destroyed?

   - If yes, would this require cross-domain file uploading directly to that server? (Anyone know if this is how youtube or the big sites do it?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your system correctly, your best approach is probably something more like this:

- In your web front-end, store the audio and create a "task" indicating that the audio needs to be processed.
- Run a background task that pulls tasks and does the processing. At the end of the task, the user can be notified (if necessary) and database state can be updated or whatever.

Your tasks should be written so that if they fail partway through, they can be re-executed from the start without causing problems. You can run multiple background tasks and web front-ends in this architecture.

A good way to write tasks is using a message passing system like [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol). There are cheap services like [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) that will do this for you. You can, of course, also build your own on top of any database, but this may require polling.

Finally, you might find it faster and more efficient to use a service like [zencoder](http://zencoder.com) to do your transcoding, because they can parallelize the work and probably handle more input formats, but it may not be compatible with your processing.

Comment: I would prefer not to use an external service for transcoding since we already have the transcoding handled ourselves, but it's more of a question about how we should scale while allowing for file uploads. My assumption was that, as long as we are allowing file uploads on any frontend web instance, it would be much more difficult to scale horizontally because that instance could theoretically be destroyed whenever there is a reduction in traffic, which could happen to be in the middle of a file upload. In that case, would it be better to handle all file uploading on one centralized server?

Comment: The zencoder suggestion was simply a suggestion for something else to consider, not the main point.

Comment: Without knowing specifics of your traffic and budget I can't tell you if having one upload server or more is better. For large uploads I usually redirect my clients to s3, instead of tunnelling traffic or hosting the files myself. This requires a bit more intelligence on the client side, but it's more robust and dynamic.

Comment: I suppose I'm asking a bit much. I think in my case, I will either direct file uploads to s3 or a permanent ec2 instance directly from the client side. From what I've seen, I would be able to implement it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you definitely want to throw the audio processing to a background process.

Depending on the scalability involved, you might need a computer dedicated to the processing. You might want to look into other resources you can offload audio stuff too (like PCIe cards and such)

Sorry to say I know nothing about cross domain file uploading or how the big dogs do it (youtube, soundcloud ect)